# I cant export bs4 output to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I just started learning about scrapers and am trying to export links to a txt file 
but i am stuck with the error

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

def get_links():
    url = 'https://arxiv.org/list/math/new'
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.text
    soup = bs(data, 'html.parser')

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        links = link.get('href')

        with open('urlfile.txt','wb') as f:
            f.write(links)

get_links()
```

can someone please explain to me what is going wrong and how can i fix this? :)

Comment: You openned the file in byte mode....so it expects byte...
Change to         `with open('urlfile.txt','w+') as f:
            f.write(links)` This will allow you to write strings....Let me know if it resolves your problem and i'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what is wrong is this part:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    links = link.get('href')

    with open('urlfile.txt','wb') as f:
        f.write(links)
```

First, you're trying to write a string to a file opened in binary mode (`'wb'`) - you don't need binary mode here.

Second, you go through all `a href` links with your loop, and for every link you open the same file for writing. So even when you fix the mode problem, you'll overwrite your previous link with a next one - at the end, only the last one will be in the file. You need to move `open` outside the loop. 
And finally, it is probably a good idea to have a separator (`\n`) after every link you write…

```
    with open('urlfile.txt','w') as f:
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            links = link.get('href')
            if links:
                f.write(links + '\n')
```

Comment: hi, i am trying your fix now but i get a new error,   unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Comment: So it seems some of your `a` tags don't have the `href` attribute and therefore `None` is returned from `link.get('href')`… but this is a trivial workaroun, see above.

Comment: @MichaelBenHaym Even better than "thanks" is if you could accept the answer :)